# Filtering records not containing numbers

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table that has numbers in string format. Ideally the table should contain 10 digit number in string format, but it has many junk values. I wanted to filter out the records that are not ideal in nature.

Below is the sample table that I have:

```
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
|    ID_UID     | Length |            ##Comment             |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| +112323456705 |     13 | Contains special character       |
|  4323456432   |     11 | Contains blank                   |
| 3423122334    |     10 | As expected, 10 character number |
| 6758439239    |     10 | As expected, 10 character number |
| 58_4323129    |     10 | Contains special character       |
| 4567$%6790    |     10 | Contains special character       |
| 45684938901   |     11 | Is 11 characters                 |
| 4568 38901    |     10 | Contains blank                   |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---------------+--------+----------------------------+
|    ID_UID     | Length |         ##Comment          |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------+
| +112323456705 |     13 | Contains special character |
|  4323456432   |     11 | Contains blank             |
| 58_4323129    |     10 | Contains special character |
| 4567$%6790    |     10 | Contains special character |
| 45684938901   |     11 | Is 11 characters           |
| 4568 38901    |     10 | Contains blank             |
+---------------+--------+----------------------------+
```

Basically I want all the records that dont have 10 digit numbers in them.

I have tried out below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE ID_UID LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

But this does not returns any records.

Have created a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qF11saAz3E14bcxqD5qzck/0) for the same.

P.S. The columns length and ##Comment are illustrative in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `RLIKE` not `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE ID_UID RLIKE '[^0-9]'
```

Note that `%` is a `LIKE` wildcard, not a regular expression wildcard.  Also, regular expressions match the pattern anywhere it occurs, so no wildcards are needed for the beginning and end of the string.

If you want to find values that are not ten digits, then be explicit:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE ID_UID NOT RLIKE '^[0-9]{10}$'
```

Comment: I also want to ensure that the length is 10 characters. With above query I am also excluding 7th record in my original table (all digits but length is 11). Also when I try `SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE ID_UID RLIKE '[0-9]'`. I am getting all records, whereas I would want only records having all the digits. (considering that I have removed the `^` sign.